# Create reusable, resizable architectural objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, shape-keys

In my example, I have modeled a simple window, with a outer-frame, glass and inner-frame.

[image: The window]

*I did not want to use the Archimesh addon because I do not need inner geometry and I need to have specific feature like a specific slope on the frame)*

I want to be able to set the height and width of this window, which means, I do not want to scale it. I have seen many tutorials and examples, but they all force me to scale the window, which will distort the frame, and also isn't precise.

I have set up the object custom properties for this window with `Width` and `Height` properties and I want them to reflect and drive the vertices of the right and top part of the frame.

So when I change the custom property `Width`, the vertices (selected on the screenshot above), will reflect that.

I tried to be a wizard by adding shape keys and vertex groups but it just seems not to work. That approach forces me to scale the object between 0 and 1 or any other number, and i do not want that. Maybe I do not get it, please explain to me then how I need to set this up, because I do not want to calculate each time i need to adjust the window, how much scale 1.05m or 1.403m is from 1m base and then insert that in the custom property `width`.

I think you probably get it now. Think of it like in CAD software, when you set the width of the window, right part of the frame will just move to the inserted distance, without distorting the frame itself.

Comment: Blender is not a CAD software. You should look into *Geometry Nodes* if you want to create parametric objects